# Is there a GUI, package, or plugin that I can use to create InDesign-like textboxes that contain LaTeX markup?

Tags: packages, programming, textpos

I'm not very spatially aware and I'm looking for an [app](/questions/tagged/app), [program](/questions/tagged/program), [plugin](/questions/tagged/plugin), or [extension](/questions/tagged/extension) that would allow me to create [indesign](/questions/tagged/indesign)-like text boxes (that I can drag around a page and select) that can contain LaTex markup.

Is there, perhaps, a plugin for [texstudio](/questions/tagged/texstudio)?

Comment: I highly doubt there's anything that you can 'drag' around a 'page' in LaTeX.  You might want to try `LyX`, although I'm unfamiliar with its interface.  For LaTeX, there is [grid-system](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/grid-system), which is self-described thus: 'The pack­age pro­vides the means for LaTeX to im­ple­ment a grid sys­tem as known from CSS grid sys­tems. The fa­cil­ity is use­ful for cre­at­ing box lay­outs as used in brochures.'  I suspect this is still far from what you are hoping for.

Comment: Draging something around a page is a wysiwyg feature. Not possible with LaTeX, completely different approach. Sorry. But give us an example (a picture, maybe) of what you want and perhaps somebody comes with an suggestion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `flowfram` package may be what you are searching for. With `Jpgfdraw` (http://www.dickimaw-books.com/apps/jpgfdraw/index.html) you can draw boxes that can be used for the `flowfram` package. An example of the workflow can be found here: http://www.dickimaw-books.com/apps/jpgfdraw/manual/postertutorial.html and here: http://www.dickimaw-books.com/apps/jpgfdraw/manual/newstutorial.html.